# Determining whether a person received the right change for stamps

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

this is how i would approach this problem.

I would let $x$=stamps and then have the following

$500-(3x+6x)=75$

$500-(9x)=75$

$-9x=-425$

Since $x$ is not an integer then he did not receive the right change.

Anyone want to confirm?

EDIT:

Let $x=$number of $3$ cent stamps and let $y=$number of $6$ cent stamps

so:

$500-(3x+6y)=75$

where $x=\dfrac{-425+6y}{-3}=\dfrac{425}{3}-{2y}$

Plugging back in:

$500-3(\frac{425}{3}-2y)-6y=500-425-6y=75$ then $y=0$

I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What makes you think that he bought same number of stamps? Maybe he bought 3 stamps for 3 cents nad 4 stamps for 6?

Comment: you expression says that he bought the same amount of 3 cents stamps as of those 6 cents stumps, but this wasn't claimed in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$500-(3x+6y)=75$$
$$(3x+6y)=425$$
$$3(x+2y)=425$$
$$(x+2y)=425/3$$
since $x+2y$ should be an integer, but $425/3$ is not we conclude that a wrong amount of change was received by that person.

Answer (score 1):

In response to : Is my answer correct?

Your answer is incorrect because you assume that he buys the same number of stamps of each kind.

You need to have two variables, one for each type of stamp.

EDIT : Now isolate $(x+2y)$ which should be an integral. And see that it isn't.

Comment: alright let me edit.